# Displaying a value associated with a maximum value

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group, max

I have a PostgreSQL database for a supermarket (it's a toy problem) and I need to find which outlet has sold the most copies of each product and display it in a query which also shows the product name, description, copies in stock across all stores, copies purchased across all stores.

I think I have the first few columns queried appropriately, as below:

```
SELECT a.ProductName, a.ProductDescription, a.StockSum, b.PurchaseSum, c.MaxSales
FROM (SELECT Product.Name AS ProductName, Product.Description AS ProductDescription
           , SUM(Stock.copies) AS StockSum
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Stock
ON Stock.product_id = Product.product_id
GROUP BY Product.name, Product.description) AS a
FULL JOIN
(SELECT Product.name AS ProductName, Product.description AS ProductDescription
      , SUM(PurchaseItem.copies) AS PurchaseSum
FROM Product
INNER JOIN PurchaseItem
ON PurchaseItem.product_id = Product.product_id
GROUP BY Product.name, Product.description) AS b;
```

But I cannot for the life of me work out how to pull the appropriate `Outlet.name` associated with the MAX of the SUM of all `PurchaseItem.copies` corresponding to a particular `product_id` at a particular store. It seems like a very complex query, and it has flummoxed me!

The structure of the database is that `Purchase` references `Outlet`, while `PurchaseItem` references `Purchase` and a single `Product` (with `PurchaseItem.copies` recording the number of sales of that product in the purchase).

Comment: I don't know about postgresql but in MSSQL you have partition by order by

Comment: @Frisbee: that's called a "window function" and Postgres does support that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @Frisbee: I think `DISTINCT ON` is superior here. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) here, but I would think there's actually a better solution with `DISTINCT ON`.

First I simplified what you had so far:

```
SELECT p.name AS product_name, p.description AS product_description
     , a.stock_sum, b.purchase_sum
     , c.max_sales, o.outlet_name   -- still missing
FROM   Product p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT product_id, SUM(copies) AS stock_sum
   FROM   Stock
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a USING (product_id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT product_id, sum(copies) AS purchase_sum
   FROM   PurchaseItem
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (product_id)
-- c, o still  missing
```

It should be considerably faster to aggregate counts before joining:

- [Why does the following join increase the query time significantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971600/939860)

Also, `LEFT JOIN` retains products in the result that don't have any purchases, yet, or aren't in stock any more.

Then add the missing parts:

```
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
          pi.product_id, pu.outlet_id, sum(copies) AS max_sales
   FROM   Purchase      pu
   JOIN   PurchaseItem  pi USING (purchase_id)
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, sum(copies) DESC NULLS LAST
   ) c  USING (product_id)
LEFT   JOIN Outlet o USING (outlet_id);
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

You can run `DISTINCT` over the results of the aggregation. Consider the sequence of events in a query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied in PHP/PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

#### Optimize performance

It's probably cheaper to scan `PurchaseItem` only once, using a CTE. But this also adds some overhead. You'll have to test which is faster:

```
WITH ct AS (
   SELECT pi.product_id, pu.outlet_id, sum(pi.copies) AS sales
   FROM   PurchaseItem  pi 
   JOIN   Purchase      pu USING (purchase_id)
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
SELECT p.name AS product_name, p.description AS product_description
     , a.stock_sum, b.purchase_sum
     , c.max_sales, o.outlet_name
FROM   Product p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT product_id, SUM(copies) AS stock_sum
   FROM   Stock
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a USING (product_id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT product_id, sum(sales) AS purchase_sum
   FROM   ct
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (product_id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
          product_id, outlet_id, sales AS max_sales
   FROM   ct
   ORDER  BY product_id, sales DESC
   ) c  USING (product_id)
LEFT   JOIN Outlet o USING (outlet_id);
```

Test performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) (a couple of times to exclude caching effects).

Answer (score 0):

I think I could give you a better answer if you added the schema for the tables involved and maybe some sample data. That being said if I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish correctly I'd probably go with a query more like the below. With the way I'm reading your query I'm not really seeing what the point in having the MAX of the SUM is when you are needing to restrict your results to a certain store and item.  Anyhow, see below. It's a bit simpler than your query was and the aliases are different, but should be fairly easy to follow I believe.

```
SELECT p.Name AS [Product Name], 
       p.Description AS [Product Description],
       SUM(stock.copies) AS [Stock Sum],
       SUM(i.copies) AS [Purchase Sum],
       MAX(SUM(i.copies)) AS [Max Sum Purchase Items],
       o.OutletName AS [Outlet Name]
FROM Product as p
INNER JOIN Stock s
  ON s.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN PurchaseItem i
  ON i.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN Outlet o
   ON o.outlet_id = p.outlet_id
WHERE p.product_id = <xxxxxxx>
  AND o.outlet_id = <xxxxxxx>
GROUP BY p.name, p.Description, o.OutletName
```

**UPDATED QUERY**

```
SELECT p.Name AS [Product Name], 
       p.Description AS [Product Description],
       SUM(stock.copies) AS [Stock Sum],
       SUM(i.copies) AS [Purchase Sum],
       MAX(SELECT SUM(i2.copies)
           FROM PurchaseItem i2 
           INNER JOIN Products p2
              ON i2.product_id = p2.product_ID
           INNER JOIN Outlets o2
              ON o2.outlet_id = p2.outlet_ID
           WHERE p2.product_ID = p.product_ID
             AND o2.outlet_ID = o.outlet_ID
           GROUP BY p2.product_ID, 
                    o2.outlet_ID) AS [Max Sum Purchase Items],
       o.OutletName AS [Outlet Name]
FROM Product as p
INNER JOIN Stock s
    ON s.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN PurchaseItem i
    ON i.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN Outlet o
    ON o.outlet_id = p.outlet_id
WHERE p.product_id = <xxxxxxx>
  AND o.outlet_id = <xxxxxxx>
GROUP BY p.name, p.Description, o.OutletName
```

Maybe this one then.

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't explained the task well enough. I'd like the query to output a list of all products, and for each product show the outlet where it has sold the most copies.

Comment: Thank you for trying again. The problem is that the bit "WHERE p.product_id = <xxxxx>" implies we are just looking at a single product and outlet, but I need a table listing each product in turn, and next to the product the name of the outlet where the most copies were sold. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try the query without the updated query without the WHERE clause. I had meant to take it out anyways.